# my timer in eclipse did not work properly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer

I am new to eclipse and my timer in eclipse did not work properly, this is my java. code in the timer:

```
Button countDownButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.countDown1);      
    countDownButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){

              CountDownTimer timer2 = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000){

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                        mTimeLabel1.setText("Times Up baby!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {                               

                          int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                          int minutes = seconds / 60;
                          seconds = seconds % 60;

                          mTimeLabel1.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                                                          + String.format("%02d", seconds));

                    }          
              }.start();

        }
    });
```

Basically everything is running as I wish, however, I found that if I clicked the trigger button while it is counting, it will trigger another counting without stop the previous counting. This is very embarrassing, my friend suggest me to do "switch" if the button trigger again, and I am considering to add another actions to the same button which is stop the restart counting. Which one is more preferable?

Comment: You could disable the trigger button while the timer is running?

Comment: I will add it as an answer and you could accept?

Comment: @RickardB. can u suggest how to disable the trigger button to the code i wrote? i am searching the desiring code for that, would u like to help me? sure if you put that as answer, appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the trigger button while the timer is running.

That way you will save the pain to fiqure out how to do a switch or adding other actions to the button after the first click.

You could try the `yourbutton.setEnabled(false);` to make it disabled.

if i have understood the code right, it should be

`countDownButton2.setEnabled(false);`

To enable the button again, use

`countDownButton2.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: i tried. and i realized that button will be totally disable after i do that, i would rather restart the timer than totally disable it... and i am looking for help if i can do the "restart the timer"

Comment: and you can't enable the button when the time is up?
`countDownButton2.setEnabled(true);`?

Comment: great to use this, so i can continue my practice!

Comment: I wish you the best of luck!